# How can i join the results only with specific rows in another table on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

I have these tables:

```
user_points
- user_class_id
- scoreable_id
-scoreable_type

points_interaction_system
- user_id
- points
- type

supplementary_assessments
- user_id
- points
```

In user_points table the scoreable_type will receive the model of the one of the other tables like App\Models\SupplementaryAssessment or App\Models\PointInteractionSystem and the scoreable_id the id of the model.
What i want to do is join the supplementary table records only with the rows in the user_points that have in the scoreable_type the model SupplementaryAssessment and join the points_interaction_system records only the rows in the user_points that have in the scoreable_type the model PointInteractionSystem. At the end i want sum all the points fields based on the user id.

I did something like this, but its not working:

```
DB::table('user_points')
            ->join('user_classes', function ($join) use ($user) {
                $join->on('user_points.user_class_id', '=', 'user_classes.id')
                        ->where('user_classes.user_id', $user->id);
            })
            ->leftJoin('supplementary_assessments', function ($join) {
                $join->on('user_points.scoreable_id', '=', 'supplementary_assessments.id')
                        ->where('user_points.scoreable_type', 'like', '%SupplementaryAssessment');
            })
            ->leftJoin('points_interaction_system', function ($join) {
                $join->on('user_points.scoreable_id', '=', 'points_interaction_system.id')
                        ->where('user_points.scoreable_type', 'like', '%PointInteractionSystem');
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```php
DB::table('user_points')
            ->join('user_classes', function ($join) use ($user) {
                $join->on('user_points.user_class_id', '=', 'user_classes.id')
                        ->where('user_classes.user_id', $user->id);
            })
            ->join('supplementary_assessments', function ($join) {
                $join->on('user_points.scoreable_id', '=', 'supplementary_assessments.id')
                        ->where('user_points.scoreable_type', 'like', '%SupplementaryAssessment%');
            })
            ->join('points_interaction_system', function ($join) {
                $join->on('user_points.scoreable_id', '=', 'points_interaction_system.id')
                        ->where('user_points.scoreable_type', 'like', '%PointInteractionSystem%');
            })
            ->get();
```

> Uses join instead of left-join.